# Maximum number of bounded primitive integer points in a zero-dimensional system

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-geometry

Given a set of $n$ many degree $2$ algebraically independent and thus zero-dimensional system of homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with absolute value of coefficients bound by $2^{m}$ what is the maximum number of bounded primitive (gcd of coordinates $1$) integer points possible?

1. Is it $d^{O(mn)}$ for general degree $d$ systems or much lower/higher?
2. Is there any sharp bound at all?

**Updates**

1. Even for the simple equation $x_1x_2=n$ where $n$ is a product of $O\big(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\big)$ distinct primes we can expect exponential number of primitive solutions $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb Z^2$. However here we have homogeneous system.
2. Related link but irrelevant (here I seek maximum number of integer roots) [Real points of zero-dimensional real algebraic varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184964/real-points-of-zero-dimensional-real-algebraic-varieties?rq=1).

Comment: Earlier question on degree 2 homogeneous systems from same user, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325856/reconstructing-almost-known-polynomial-from-a-system-of-polynomials-with-common