# Aligned roots of irreducible polynomials

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, galois-theory

It is well known from [this famous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182412/why-do-roots-of-polynomials-tend-to-have-absolute-value-close-to-1) that the roots of a random polynomial tend to be close to the unit circle. So I was wondering in a somewhat converse sense: **for an irreducible polynomial, is it possible that many roots are collinear (on a line other than the real or the imaginary axis)?**

Now, if we take for instance a Chebyshev polynomial $T_k(x^n-1)$, we get trivially $k$ roots on each of the $n$ rays from $O$ through each $n$th root of unity, see e.g. [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ChebyshevT[5%2C%20x%5E7-1]) for $k=5,n=7$ (left picture). But what if we want roots on a line which are *not* collinear with the origin, i.e. not proportional over $\mathbb R$? (And of course mere linear shifts should be excluded, like replacing in such a polynomial $x$ by $x-1$.)
We can easily get twice four of them on vertical lines, e.g. for [the minimal polynomial of $ \dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[4]{2}}+(\sqrt{2}+1)i $](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E8%2B12+x%5E6%2B16+x%5E5%2B42+x%5E4%2B32+x%5E3%2B68+x%5E2%2B112+x%2B73), which is  $x^8+12 x^6+16 x^5+42 x^4+32 x^3+68 x^2+112 x+73$ (right picture).
[image]

This raises several questions (remember that it is all about *irreducible* polynomials, so we could talk as well of the Galois conjugates of a given algebraic number):
Assuming that the pattern has no rotational symmetry and taking the word 'line' to exclude both axis,

> **1. Is it possible to have more than 4 roots on a line?**
>   **2. Can a line with 4 or more roots be other than horizontal or vertical? If so, which slopes can occur?**
>   **3. Is it even possible to have exactly 3 of the roots on a line?**

***EDIT: Q1 and Q3 => Yes by Ilya Bogdanov's comments. So Q2 remains, and I've added Q4:***

> **4. Is it possible that the roots make up a $p\times q$ grid where $p$, the number of rows, is not a power of $2$?**

Note that there can be patterns with only *one* line of 4 collinear roots, e-g. [the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+i+ \dfrac{i}{\sqrt[4]{2}} $](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%20x%5E8-16%20x%5E6%2B32%20x%5E5%2B84%20x%5E4-192%20x%5E3-40%20x%5E2-112%20x%2B353) , viz. ${ {4 x^8-16 x^6+32 x^5+84 x^4-192 x^3-40 x^2-112 x+353}}$:   [image]

For Q1, it might be possible to find constructions by some sort of "bifurcation" in a sense similar to what happens with the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), but I am not very sure about that. If at all, I'd conjecture that for any *[edit: vertical]* line, the number of roots it contains always is a power of 2.

EDIT: Q4 has a positive answer. (And so has Q2.) Based on the [construction of Jeremy Rouse in the related question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/338215/29783), we have e.g. $$x^{18}+6x^{15}+54x^{14}-54x^{13}+24x^{12}+378x^{11}+189x^{10}\\ -1672x^9+5184x^8+162x^7-11649x^6+13824x^5\\ +28944x^4-80904x^3+138240x^2-86400x+44992$$ whose roots come in a nice $3\times 6$ pack as displayed here:
[image]

Comment: If you have some $\xi$ such that its minimal polynomial $P(x)$ has several collinear roots, you may choose some non-real $\eta$ whose minimal polynomial remains irreducible in the splitting field of $P$; then the minimal polynomial of $\eta\xi$ also has the same number of roots lying on the line rotated by $\arg\eta$ (and scaled by $|\eta|$).

Comment: Also, you may see that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2+i/(\root4\of 2+\root4\of 3+\root4\of5+\root4\of7)$ has quite more collinear roots...

Comment: Do you mean polynomial with integer coefficients? (Otherwise just choose the roots)?

Comment: As for Q3, why not take three real roots of an irreducible degree 3 polynomial and shif them by $i\sqrt n$? You may then rotate them if you wish.

Comment: @joro yes, of course I mean irreducible over the integers.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov For your last comment: Oh sure, how could I miss such a simple idea? So e.g. $x^6+2 x^3+21 x^2-18 x+51$.

Comment: Even better when shifting by $i\cos\frac{\pi}{5}$ which yields a 4×3 grid! Or by $i\cos\frac{\pi}{20}$ which yields a 8×3 grid.There may be some of that bifurcation here.

Comment: Are you aware of Theodore Motzkin's paper *Sur l'equation irreductible $z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 = 0$, $n > 1$, a coefficients complexes entiers, dont toutes les racines sont sur une droite. Les $11$ classes de droites admissibles* (Comptes Rendues hebdomadaires..., 1945)?

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov No, I'm not. Can you access it? Even though the subject seems quite different (especially considering complex coefficients), maybe some of the methods are applicable here?

Comment: @Wolfgang: I have not looked at it closely, but it describes all classes of lines $L \subset \mathbb{C}$ that contain all complex roots of a monic irreducible polynomial of arbitrarily large degree over the Gaussian ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. This could be relevant since the $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$-orbit of an algebraic number partitions into (at most) two $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}(i))$-orbits, giving irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose roots are covered by the union of two lines: $L$ and its complex conjugate.

Comment: I took this reference from the endnotes in Chapter 2.4.3 of Narkiewicz's *Elementary and Analytic Theory of Algebraic Numbers*. This contains some further references (Robinson, Ennola, Smyth,...) to similar questions which could be of interest to you.